# Opening txt file on chrome return html document

Tags: javascript

When I open a text file on Chrome, the browser returns a HTML document in element tab at dev tools. I want to know what rendering engine parses the text from `.txt` file to HTML? If parsed, does the text also have a DOM tree?

I searched on Google and also asked Chat GPT.

Comment: It's likely that your browser 
1) converts provided text to HTML's [```TEXT_NODE```][1]
2) inserts it to document's body
What do you mean by 'parsing' text? If it's plain text there is no need to parse .. 

  [1]: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node

Comment: converting provided text to html text node does not mean parsing html by using rendering engine?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the mime type of the document.
If you want chrome to treat your file as a raw text file you should add the header:

```
Content-Type: text/plain
```